# Lua - iterator with variable number of arguments

Tags: lua, iterator, iteration

I've been trying to understand how Lua iterators work and behave. While closures are pretty clear to me, I've been having difficulties working with stateless iterators.

The easiest tasks, like re-implementing ipairs or pairs, are fairly clear to me. But what if I want to write an iterator, that takes in a variable number of tables and iterates through them? 
For example,

```
for i in iter({1,2,3}, {'a', 'b', 'c'}, {100, 101}, {}) do
    print(i)
end
--I would expect it to write: 1, 2, 3, a, b, c, 100, 101
```

I've been trying to find some useful information on the internet, but all I've seen were the same simple examples being worked on over and over again. So, any tips and advice are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the iterator you are talking about should look like this :
EDIT : replaced usage of 2 indexes with a single array holding the two indexes.

```
function iter_variable (a, indexArr)
  indexArr[2] = indexArr[2] + 1
  local v = a[indexArr[1]][indexArr[2]]
  if v then
    return indexArr, v
  else
    -- end of current internal DS, move on to the next internal DS
    indexArr[1] = indexArr[1] + 1
    indexArr[2] = 1
    local v = a[indexArr[1]][indexArr[2]]
    if v then
        return indexArr, v
    end
  end
end

function ipairs_variable (...)
  local a = {...}
  return iter_variable, a, {1,0}
end

for i, v in ipairs_variable({1,2,3}, {'a', 'b', 'c'}, {100, 101}, {}) do
  print(v)
end
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working for me, as j is always a nil. It is probably because of how for loop works in Lua. Iterator will always be called with only two arguments - state and seed, which makes it impossible to index a table like that, using third (I think so, at least).

Comment: Refactored suggested solution following your comment on the state/seed model.

Comment: I haven't thought about making it seedless! Good idea. Although, I suggested few changes to your answer, making it an actual Lua program (in Lua we start indexing tables from 1, instead of 0). Now it also works with list of arguments. Once you accept the edits, I can accept the answer.

Comment: @PoorBoi : Happy to help buddy, and even happier with your fine tuning of the solution.

Comment: It seems `{}` is used as mandatory terminator.  That's C-ish style, not Lua-ish  :-)